# How to organise the structure of a 3D game?

Tags: python, architecture, 3d, pyglet

This is a bit of a vague question but bear with me. I am in the process of writing a game using Python/Pyglet and openGL. I currently have it structured so that there is an object called 'world', in this are other objects with other objects inside them etc. I did it this way because for instance one part of the game is a platform with other objects on it, and when I tilt the platform I want the objects on it to tilt with it. So I do platform.draw() which calls glRotate, glTranslate, then draw each of the objects saving the modelview matrix inbetween, this way all the objects on the platform move together.
The first question is, is this a sensible way to organise things or should I be using some other method?

I don't have a camera class, currently I am just translating the whole world or parts of it to give the illusion of movement. However, in the future I want to be able to switch viewpoints between objects, so for instance switch from looking down onto the world from above to a 1st person view from one of the objects in the world. So the second question is what is the best way to structure my program so that this will be achievable in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Not probably a full answer, but i think a full one would take a whole book...

What you are doing with your representation of the world in a hierarchy is very similar to what is usually known as "scene-graph", and it is a good idea in many cases. A good example of a library to do precisly this is [Open Scene Graph](http://openscenegraph.org).

About "translating the world", unless you are really transforming all the vertices every time, it is also perfectly fine. It is just a matter of relative point of view and what your really have is the same that a camera matrix. You can see the transformation as placing the camera in the world, or as moving the world in front of the camera.

Comment: The problem is that when I want to do something with one of the objects in my world I am having to do world.object1.object2.object3.do_something(), its getting a bit ugly. I am also having to pass a pointer to the rest of the world to each object, not that this is a huge problem really.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the logic into a seperate module / into seperate classes/functions.
In my 2D-Game I have a `GameLogic` class which simplifies registering it's methods for certain events or scheduling them (and unregistering+unscheduling them), and I created a `@state_wrapper` decorator which injects a simple new-style object as state-storage for that method. If you do it like that you don't have to pass the pointer to all your world objects, only the event-methods have to get access to your objects.

But I wouldn't claim that this is the best solution ;)